# WindowActivityBar=false not working

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which will be on embedded device, and I need to remove ActionBar alongside the TitleBar and ContentOverlay.
I found a solution and inserted the following in my styles:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

and also add the line to my activity in AndroidManifest:

```
android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
```

and in the end I got no title bar, no content overlay, however the ActionBar is still there. Please advice. I use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` and my targetSdkVersion is 18.

Comment: By setting Action Bar false you are only disable the action bar so you need to hide it by writing below code in your activity java file to hide it.

getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

This should be at top just before setContentView();

Comment: But the Action Bar still functions normally in my activity.

Comment: do you explicitly set toolbar? in your activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small mistakes in XML can cause very strange problems,
which are not always reported accurately by the build process.
I tend to shy away from changing XML, when I can do it in java.
Java gives you more control.

```
programmatically remove action bar
----------------------------------
from normal activity

getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();

if your using support activity

getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();

and from the Fragment you can do it

getActivity().getActionbar().hide();
getActivity().getActionbar().show();

remove title bar
----------------

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}

ActionBar ContentOverlay
------------------------
1) Request for actionbar overlay programmatically by calling

       getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

// this 'requestFeature()' must be requested from your activity 'onCreate()' method
// before calling for 'setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)':
2) set the actionbar color by calling setBackgroundDrawable() like so:
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00212121")) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your style's parent like this :

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Example

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: doesn't help either :(